# GAE deploy won't work anymore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

So I had trouble with GAE. I started by trying to delete every instance running, versions, buckets, etc, thinking that it would reset the state of the deployment.

Now I have a broken project (permanent 503) and obscure messages :

```
Caught non-retryable exception while listing gs://staging.<app-name>.appspot.com/: 

BucketNotFoundException: 404 gs://staging.<app-name>.appspot.com bucket does not exist.

CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync

2015-11-05 22:11:13,305 DEBUG    root            (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Could not synchronize files. The gsutil command exited with status [1].
```

When I try to create said bucket in 'Storage', I have a "Backend Error".

What are my options ? Delete the GCloud project entirely and start over ?

Comment: When you go to `https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser?project=<app-name>` is there a bucket called `staging.<app-name>.appspot.com`?

Comment: no. I tried to create it but got a "Backend error" and when you input a name with '-' it says you would have to prove ownership of the bucket

Comment: so did you prove ownership of the domain? (not bucket). seems you need to google that

Comment: I can't prove ownership of a bucket that doesn't exist, won't create, for a GAE app that doesn't deploy ... Still in 503 after 48h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in the current SDK. There is an issue here about it: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=321

The current workaround is:

> Turning off the appengine api seems to fix the problem:
>
> `gcloud config set app/use_appengine_api false`

Comment: I got bit by it today too.